# Размер блока от количества текста

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно сделать такой блок http://prntscr.com/b5mg8m, проблема в чем, как реализовать ширину 6 блоков зависящих от длины текста, что бы блоки выравнивались по всей ширине и желательно что бы не было проблем с адаптацией

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http://caniuse.com - display:flex](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.block {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.block-item {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .block {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-item">
    <h3>block-item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="block-item">
    <h3>block</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="block-item">
    <h3>block</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="block-item">
    <h3>block-item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="block-item">
    <h3>block</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="block-item">
    <h3>block-item</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: за флекс даже не подумал, спасибо

Comment: bootstrap 4 на flex сейчас работает

Comment: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#mixins - float:left

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего использовать CSS/HTML фреймворк, например,
 [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)
Он адаптивный, на офф сайте и в интернетах полно инструкций :)

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="span2">...1</div>
      <div class="span2">...2</div>
      <div class="span2">...3</div>
      <div class="span2">...4</div>
      <div class="span2">...5</div>
      <div class="span2">...6</div>
    </div>
```

Удачи!

Comment: Вообще не то...